# Find $A^4$ if eigen values and eigen vectors of A are given

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The eigen values a matrix A are 0,1,3.
The corresponding eigen vectors are 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
        1  \\
        1  \\
        1  \\
        \end{bmatrix},
     \begin{bmatrix}
        1  \\
        0  \\
        -1  \\
        \end{bmatrix},
     \begin{bmatrix}
        1  \\
        -2  \\
        1  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Need to find $A^4$.

Comment: eigenvalues are $0^4, 1^4$ and $3^4$ and eigenvectors are the same

Comment: Can you share a proof of the above result?

Comment: $A^2v = A(Av)=A(\lambda v) = \lambda (Av) = \lambda^2 v$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing the matrix defined by the eigenvalues is trivial and is given by $$D =\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 3
\end{array} \right).$$ Now the matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors is given by $$P =\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
  1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & -2 \\
  1 & -1 & 1
\end{array} \right).$$ The required matrix can be obtained by changing to the standard coordinate bases by computing $A = PDP^{-1} $. Now we thus get $$\boxed {A^4 =PD^4P^{-1}} $$

Can you take it from here? Hope it helps.